# How to check values when state is changes?

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs(ui-route) in my project .

Before some states is loading I need to check the global variable in my project,
if global variable is `null` I need to redirect the user to specific state.

Any idea how can I implement it?

How do I check the global variable each time when state is changing?

**UPDATE**
My global variable is a field in service.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
angular.module('app')
.run(function(myService, $rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if(myService.field) {
        $state.go('ohMyGod');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think I can use  $state.go('ohMyGod'); in run method?